# yo angular-fullstack heroku deployment failure

Tags: angularjs, heroku, yeoman-generator, angular-fullstack

I'm using an out of the box yo angular-fullstack (without the mongo).  when I use

```
yo angular-fullstack:heroku
```

everything seems to deploy fine. When I "cd dist && heroku open" the server seems to run and tries to load but I get the following error:

```
ncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'sampleApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I have found this post https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/164 but it didn't help :(.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: can you check the module name that you use in html (`ng-app="sampleApp"`) is the same with the one used when declaring the module in javascript? `angular.module('sampleApp',[])`

Comment: This was exactly the problem. I copied my client code over to a new node with a different app name.

Thanks!